# The field that I set on an global array does not persist

Tags: php

On my PHP web-page I have a global array:

```
$test = array();
```

Then I invoke this function:

```
function f () 
{
    global $test;

    init( $test );
    $test['foo'] // Error: undefined index "foo"
}
```

which in turn invokes this function:

```
function init ( $test )
{
    $test['foo'] = 'bar';
    $test['foo'] // evaluates to'bar'
}
```

As you can see, I get an error. The "foo" field that I've added to the array inside `init()` did not persist. Why does this happen? I thought I was mutating the global `$test` inside `init()`, but it seems that I'm not doing that. What's going on here, and how can I set a "foo" field inside `init()` that persists?

Comment: You should try and avoid globals as much as possible, as it makes your code much harder to mainain in the long run

Comment: @WayneC I have only one global - `$page` - which stores all the information for the web-page. I work with this global in all my functions. I guess I should be having a Page class instead, but I haven't learned classes yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing `$test` to `init` by value, not by reference.  The `$test` inside `init` is  a local variable that just happens to contain the value of the global `$test`.

You either need to pass the array by reference, by changing the `init`'s function signature:

```
function init ( &$test )
{
    $test['foo'] = 'bar';
    $test['foo'] // evaluates to'bar'
}
```

Use `global $test` in `init`.

```
function init ()
{
    global $test;

    $test['foo'] = 'bar';
    $test['foo'] // evaluates to'bar'
}
```

Or have `init` return the array (which means you need to do `$test = init( $test );`):

```
function init ( $test )
{
    $test['foo'] = 'bar';
    $test['foo'] // evaluates to'bar'

    return $test;
}
```

Comment: I get this message in PHPStorm: "*Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed in PHP 5.4*"

Comment: You are putting the reference in the wrong place, it needs to be on the definition and not the call

Answer (score 2):

Arrays aren't passed by reference automatically. So in init $test is a copy of the array.

You either need to [pass it by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) eg.

```
function init (&$test) {
```

Or a better approach would be to return it from init.

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass the variable by reference if you want to modify it:

```
function init ( &$test )
{
    $test['foo'] = 'bar';
    $test['foo'] // evaluates to'bar'
}
```