# Unable to add new fields to array within foreach

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a 2-dimensional array:

```
$test = array(
    "foo" => array(
        'a' => 1,
        'b' => 2,
        'c' => 3
    ),
    "bar" => array(
        'a' => 1,
        'b' => 2,
        'c' => 3
    ),
    "baz" => array(
        'a' => 1,
        'b' => 2,
        'c' => 3
    )
);
```

I would like to add a field named `'d'` with the value `4` to each element of the outer array, so that the resulting array becomes:

```
array(
    "foo" => array(
        'a' => 1,
        'b' => 2,
        'c' => 3,
        'd' => 4
    ),
    "bar" => array(
        'a' => 1,
        'b' => 2,
        'c' => 3,
        'd' => 4
    ),
    "baz" => array(
        'a' => 1,
        'b' => 2,
        'c' => 3,
        'd' => 4
    )
)
```

I've tried this:

```
foreach ( $test as $elem ) 
{
    $elem['d'] = 4;
}
```

which doesn't work. What am I doing wrong, and how can I make this work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Arrays and primitives are passed by value in PHP (though objects are passed by reference). One method to overcome this in a `foreach` loop is to access the subarrays by reference in the loop:

```
// Call $elem by reference with &
foreach ( $test as &$elem ) {
    $elem['d'] = 4;
}

print_r($test);
array(3) {
  ["foo"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["a"]=>
    int(1)
    ["b"]=>
    int(2)
    ["c"]=>
    int(3)
    ["d"]=>
    int(4)
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Heh. Funny how I've asked [a very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13146086/425275) earlier today. So PHP is by default "pass-by-value", and "pass-by-reference" has to be explicitly enforced via `&`. Nice how PHP offers both methods, JavaScript doesn't have that, i.e. it's pass-by-reference only.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Objects are passed by reference.  Arrays and primitives are passed by value by default

Answer (score 3):

```
$test = array(
    "foo" => array(
        'a' => 1,
        'b' => 2,
        'c' => 3
    ),
    "bar" => array(
        'a' => 1,
        'b' => 2,
        'c' => 3
    ),
    "baz" => array(
        'a' => 1,
        'b' => 2,
        'c' => 3
    )
);

foreach($test as $key => $val)
    $test[$key]['d'] = 4;

print_r($test);
```

Comment: The problem is, my actual code is `foreach( $page["data"]["stuff"] as $key => $val ) {`, so I would have to write `$page["data"]["stuff"][$key]` a bunch of times, which is too much repetition for my taste.

Answer (score 0):

You can exploit php function and callback:

```
array_walk($test, function ( & $value) {                                                                                                                                                            
     $value['d'] = 4;
});
```